# How to query for >= to <= in for column values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contain a column named 'extension' and its varchar.the values in 'extension' column are ..

```
00,5011,5014,5018,11111
```

Now as per my requirement i want to query where extension is greater than equal to  '00' and less than equal to '11111'.On executing this query i need to get all the values present in between these values but its not happening with 'between' query. i tried it with greater than less than also but again its giving error..

I am stuck in this situation.Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Is this value for a single row? Or there's one value per row and you just listed them this way?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  Its one value per row..

Comment: It is not clear if you want to consider '00' as a string or as a number... Zero is `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where cast(extension as signed) > 00 AND cast(extension as signed) < 11111
```